# How to end LOAD DATA INFILE statement in MYSQL, ERROR 1261

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm attempting to load a .txt file into the existing *invoice* table.
When trying LOAD DATA INFILE, MYSQL goes through all of the rows in my .txt file then throws this error message.

`'Error Code: 1261. Row 541909 doesn't contain data for all columns'.`

It's obviously going through every row of data then gets to the next row and reads it as part of the dataset. Is there a way to limit the rows read or an END statement I am missing? This file was a .csv but I found out the dataset was littered with random commas in strings.

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/e_commerce_data.txt'
INTO TABLE invoice
CHARACTER SET latin1
fields terminated by '  '
lines terminated by '\r'
ignore 1 lines;
```

Comment: your configuration looks not right how sure are you about \r check th eline endings with an hex editor

Comment: If strings in your CSV file are quoted then you can use `ENCLOSED BY '"'`. That will prevent comma problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759199/load-data-infile-dealing-with-fields-with-comma

Comment: @nbk `lines terminated by '\r\n'` worked for me. thanks for the comment.